# A more efficient way of saving 125 columns in a Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a rather large table that has 125 data inputs, each of which has to be saved in a separate column.

I have named each HTML input as 1,2,3 etc... and the same within the table, to hopefully help things.

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
$observation = new Observation();
$observation->site_id = Input::get('site_id');
$observation->result = Input::get('1');
$observation->result_id = '1';
$observation->save();
```

Is there a way I could use a loop to iterate through the 125 data inputs (Input::get('X') and result_id = 'X') and then save them all?

Comment: Why wouldn't you try a for loop from 1 to 125?

Comment: I thought that may be a feasible answer, but I'm unsure how to loop and save them? Can I save them in an array whilst looping and then just call the ->save() function?

Comment: You want everything to be stored in 125 rows. Right? Not columns?

Comment: Yes, to be saved in 125 rows.

Comment: You can use the laravel's insert method. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=1; $i<=125; $i++) {

    $data[$i] = [
        'site_id'=>Input::get('site_id'),
        'result'=>Input::get($i), 'result_id'=>$i
    ];
}
```

Using Query builder:

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data); // Change this with your table name.
```

and if you want to use Eloquent:

```
Model::insert($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jilson Thomas.

Comment: Don't forget to include timestamps also if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this pattern in your controller to handle creating new Observations and editing existing Observations without worrying about the specific attribute names:

```
// get all non-empty inputs except 'token' 
$inputs = array_filter(Input::except('_token'), 'strlen');

// assuming 'id' is your primary key and sent as an input in your form
if (Input::has('id'))
{
    // An edit

    $id = Input::get('id');
    $observation = Observation::find($id);

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) 
    {
            $observation->$key = $value;
    }
}
else
{
    // A create

    $observation = new Observation($inputs);
}
```

This solution doesn't force you to use sequential column names or html input names like 1..125 and will allow you to use more meaningful column names if you prefer. However, it does assume that your column names (and therefore object attributes) are the same as the html input names.

Related, but you might also like to know that if you use the HTML helpers in the Blade view template to construct your form, and open the form with Form::model, it will fill even fill in the values of the inputs using the object that you pass to it.

For example, in the view:

```
{{ Form::model($observation) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @mmccaff. Both have given helpful and insightful answers.